# How do I know I have reached the end of a Cloudant set of results?

Tags: ibm-cloud, couchdb, cloudant

If I am paginating through a set of results on a Cloudant database, how do I know that I have reached the end of the result set?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the query method employed. If you are paginating a Cloudant Search or a Cloudant Query, then the API results will contain a `bookmark` parameter, which allows you to fetch the next page of results. When the returned bookmark value is `nil`, then you have reached the end of your result set.

If you are trying to paginate a Cloudant View or `_all_docs`, it is more tricky because there is no `bookmark` parameter. In this case, if the set of results you got is less than you expected, e.g. if you were paginating in sets of 10 results but you only got four back, then you can be sure that you have reached the end.

Also, be aware that in this case, there can be performance issues with paginating large sets. You can read more about that in [this blog post](https://blog.cloudant.com/2019/10/25/Paginating-all_docs-and-views.html).

You can read more about bookmarks in [this blog post](https://blog.cloudant.com/2019/05/31/Paging-with-Cloudant-Bookmarks.html)